# i18n translate dynamic text with spacing

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-i18n

I'm not able to translate dynamic text with spacing, see example below.

**sample.ts**

```
dynamicTexts = ['Date','Hello World']
```

**sample.html**

```
<span i18n="@@sample" *ngFor="let dynamicText of dynamicTexts">
    {dynamicText, select, other { {{ dynamicText }} } }
</span>
```

**messages.xlf**

```
<trans-unit id="sample" datatype="html">
    <source>{VAR_SELECT, select, other {<x id="INTERPOLATION" equiv-text="{{ dynamicText }}"/> } }</source>
    <target>{VAR_SELECT, select, Date {Translated Date} Hello World {Translated Hello World} other {<x id="INTERPOLATION" equiv-text="{{ dynamicText }}"/>} }</target>
</trans-unit>
```

**sample.html current result**

```
<span>
    Translated Date
</span>
<span>
    Hello World
</span>
```

**sample.html expected result**

```
<span>
    Translated Date
</span>
<span>
    Translated Hello World
</span>
```

- I'm able to translate 'Date'(text **without spacing**) to 'Translated Date'
- I'm not able to translate 'Hello World'(text **with spacing**) to 'Translated Hello World'

Please Help

Comment: Could you please provide the text you would like to have inside that span after compilation - the resulting span element after translation?

Comment: @Erbsenkoenig
edited and added current and expected result